# CSS - centre align dynamically created drop-down list

Tags: javascript, css, html-select

I created a drop-down box with the following code:

```
var s = $('<select/>',{id:"subCategory"});
```

Would someone be able to tell me how I can centre-align this using CSS?

This is a bit more of my code:

```
JavaScript

var a = $('<h3/>',{id:"h3SubCategories", text:"Sub Categories"});
a.appendTo("#subCategories");

// add the subcategory drop-down box.               
s.appendTo("#subCategories");

HTML

<div id="subCategories">            
    <div id='loadingDiv1'>
            Please wait...  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhHRx.gif" />
    </div> 
</div>
```

`#loadingDiv1` is shown and hidden at various times.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do it.

```
#subCategory
{
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
  display:block;
}
```

Here is the **[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bjyQk/)** for the same.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx for the upvote. But I should leave for the OP to decide whether he is fine with this or not. I appreciate your sincerity. - @Fags

Comment: Fags,I appreciate that you upvoted Nathan and deleted you answer. Very few ppl on SO do that

Comment: Rightly agreed @MarsOne. But I suggest she should have left her answer for the OP to decide whether he is fine with the answer or not.

Comment: @NathanLee  i want 1 help in css

Comment: Thanks Nathan Lee, however, this solution doesn't seem to change the alignment for me. I have added more code above in the hope that it may shed some light as to why your solution isn't working in my case. Thank you again for your help.